# Xamarin Forms C# open local file in webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, local-files

I am currently working on a project, and it has a live chat, the chat can send messages with an attachment(image, videos, pdf, doc and html files), the attachment is appearing and clickable.
I want to open the file (if it was an html file) in a webview, but this method is implemented in a custom ViewCell, so I can't use the same costumed method which I used in my navigated pages which is:

```
async void myWebview(){
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new WebViewPage(fileSource));
}
```

I can't use Navigation in my costumed cell and I tried using bindingContext with other page and it didn't work

is there a way to open a new webview without navigation?

Comment: why don't you use Messaging to send a Message to your page requesting that it load the file?

Comment: it didn't work, because the code it became complicated since it is a team who is working on it, and they change things every while

Comment: that's beyond the scope of SO to help you with